# Angular 2 project structure

Tags: angular, project

Instead of every time doing ng new project_name what is the alternative to getting the project structure. what if I do have node modules folder downloaded and creating the e2e and project structure thereafter. Or I just have another alternative to it like a fully new project structure downloaded once and use anywhere and every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find your answer in their blog, under the schematics article :

[**Angular Schematics**](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2)

That's basically a way to create default projects that you will be able to reuse in other projects.

Comment: schematics are used to change a component in tree structure but i just want to get new file structure every time  i create a new project without doing ng new projectname as it consumes a lot of time downloading node modules and other file of > 200 MB range

Comment: If the download size is your only issue, simply copy and paste the folder into your projects. I wouldn't do that though, since generating a new project takes the latest versions of the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I would say to spend some time and read the documentation :

https://angular.io/guide/architecture

It will help you to clarify all your questions.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Yes, the title is about the structure, but the question is totally different. Focus on the last sentence and you will understand.

Comment: @trichetriche yes i asked about getting the one structure and use it anywhere becuase it will be hectic to do npm new projectname everytime since aroung 200 MB are being downloaded i donot know why people have given the answer 2 ups

Comment: Three actually, I downvoted it. A lot of people don't even take time to read the question now, but I don't blame them, a lot of questions are poorly asked. Have you taken a look at my answer to you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [generator-ngx-rocket](https://github.com/ngx-rocket/generator-ngx-rocket). It's a extensible Angular 5+ enterprise-grade project generator.
Hope I help!

Answer (score 0):

This article explane a good practies about angular project structue from how you can divied you components , pages , modules

https://medium.com/@motcowley/angular-folder-structure-d1809be95542

right now the best way to create angular project is to use angular cli , before there is a lot of people during the early version of angular the create seed project you can look to son example